# JPEGs uploaded to Plone are black-and-white and have lines through them

Tags: python, jpeg, plone, zope

I have a Plone 5 installation running on AWS, installed with Bitnami's Plone image.

The system information is as follows:

- Plone 5.0.7 (5017)
- CMF 2.2.10
- Zope 2.13.26
- Python 2.7.13 (default,
  Jul 26 2017, 16:31:12) [GCC 4.3.0] PIL 1.1.7

We're having an issue - whenever a JPEG is uploaded (through the 'New Image' function, or as part of a post, regardless of the method), the JPEG is black-and-white and has vertical lines going through it, even if the original photo was full color.

The screenshot below is an example of what happens whenever we upload ANY JPEG:

[image]

Perhaps there is something wrong with the JPEG compression engine that Plone is using? The strange thing is that all other image formats work perfectly.

Has anyone experienced this issue before or does anybody have any clue how to go about solving it? I would just use use other image formats, but this is a community-based site and it's impractial for us to disallow the use of JPEGs.

Comment: For best results, please post Plone questions on our forum at https://community.plone.org